# How to store similar objects with diferent behavior?

Tags: java, oop

For example, I need to build object WebPage, that has elements.

```
class WebPage {
    List<Element> elements;
}
```

ok, but i think, that Element could be `<input>` or `<select>`. 
In this way i should make interface

```
interface Element{
    RenderedElement render();
}
```

and implement Input and Select classes based on it.

```
class Input implements Element {
    String name;
    String value;
    RenderedElement render() { ... }
}

class Select implements Element {
    String name;
    List<Option> options;
    RenderedElement render() { ... }
}
```

and ok, no problem, I even can draw any element from WebPage, coz i have `render()` method..

But what if I want to store this WebPage in DB? I don't know real type of every element in this List and i should use magic to detect it.
Can you tell me design pattern I need to use in this situation?

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? Anyway the idea is to save an additional column, which you can call`type`, which will serve as a discriminator when you load the entities.

Comment: @NiVeR nope, it's pet project on H2. yep, I've thought about special Type ENUM, but... it smells like `hackz`, no? i hoped that there is silver bullet that can help in such cases :)

Comment: You could just serialize your classes (using Java serialization, JSON, custom serialization, etc.) and store it either in a text or clob field or JSON field (if your db supports it).

Comment: It is no hack, hibernate integrates this as table inheritance strategy

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA join table [inheritance strategy](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro002.htm), it will create a table for similar attributes, and specific tables for the classes, or even, if you want a more simple strategy, use jackson with his [inheritance strategy](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance) and store the WebPage objects in a JSON file.